# What does "install\r" error mean in Reactjs with Docker using yarn?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows, docker, yarnpkg

I created a Reactjs application with Docker setup. I am using Windows 10. After building, the container just keeps restarting producing errors on logs:

[Docker Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJ7ht.png)

[Logs Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9SYZO.png)

[Browser Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sI4md.png)

```
yarn run v1.22.5
error Command "install\r" not found.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
: not foundotup.sh: line 3: 
/var/www/bootup.sh: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file (expecting "then")
```

Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:12.20.0-alpine3.10

WORKDIR /var/www

COPY package.json /var/www/
RUN yarn install

COPY . /var/www/

# Install create-react-app package
RUN yarn global add react-scripts

EXPOSE 3000

ADD ./bootup.sh /var/www
RUN cd /var/www
RUN chmod +x /var/www/bootup.sh
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  frontend:
    build: .
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    working_dir: /var/www/
    ports:
      - '3002:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/var/www'
      - /var/www/node_modules
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true yarn start
    command: /var/www/bootup.sh ${SSL_ON}
```

bootup.sh

```
# Install Dependencies
yarn install

# Start the react app
if [ "$1" == "true" ]
then
  yarn start-https
else
  yarn start
fi
```

I tried restarting it, killing the container, cloned the repository again, but the issue is still occurring.

I cloned the repo in Ubuntu using another laptop, none of these errors occur, only on windows. If anyone has any idea what this means, it would be a great help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It could be that line endings in your bootup.sh file are Windows style \r\n. Unix style is just \n and that could be why it's complaining about the extra \r.

Comment: I added images to visually see the errors and occurrences.

Comment: @HansKilian could you specify which part?

Comment: I've already been as specific as I can, I think. Your bootup.sh is saved in the wrong format. You need to open it in an editor that can save it with Unix style line endings and save it from in there.

Comment: @HansKilian Thank you so much. I tried you're suggestion and followed this https://support.nesi.org.nz/hc/en-gb/articles/218032857-Converting-from-Windows-style-to-UNIX-style-line-endings and it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue based on @HansKilian comment about line-endings. I followed this link on how to convert `bootup.sh` file with the proper UNIX-style line endings: https://support.nesi.org.nz/hc/en-gb/articles/218032857-Converting-from-Windows-style-to-UNIX-style-line-endings